# Would like to know how to filter results from a specific (nested, table within table) table heading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Pic explaining the dilemma]
Have been dabbling around with this piece of code, only I could do with some input. Could really do with a follow up working examples altered code snippet if at all possible. Need to figure the filter/search - returning results being limited to a specified table heading ('th/tr' - tags), namely the Title heading and search within ONLY this area, though displaying the whole cells still (Title, Description and Date).Any questions I'll be pleased to help.
[image: Pic showing how I would like the results to operate and look]

```js
var input, table, rows, noMatches, markInstance;

$(document).ready(function init() {
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');
  table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  markInstance = new Mark(table);
  input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));
});

function ContactsearchFX() {
  resetContent();
  markInstance.unmark({
    done: highlightMatches
  });
}

function resetContent() {
  $('.noMatchErrorText').remove();
  //Remove this line to have a log of searches

  //noMatches.textContent = '';
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    $(row).removeClass('show');
  });
}

function highlightMatches() {
  markInstance.mark(input.value, {
    each: showRow,
    noMatch: onNoMatches,
  })
}

function showRow(element) {
  //alert(element);
  $(element).parents('tr').addClass('show');
  $(element).parents('tr').siblings('tr').addClass('show');
  //Parents incase of several nestings
}

function onNoMatches(text) {
  $('#myInput').after('<p class="noMatchErrorText">No records match: "' + text + '"</p>');
}
```

```css
.input-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myInput:invalid~.hints {
  display: block;
}

#noMatches:empty,
#noMatches:empty+.hints {
  display: none;
}

.style1 tr {
  display: none;
}

.style1 .show {
  display: table-row;
}

mark {
  background: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.style1 {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/mark.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <label>
    Search Titles: 
    <input id="myInput" type="text" required
       placeholder="Search Titles" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="hintsWrap">
  <p id="noMatches"></p>
  <p class="hints">
    Hints: type "Title1", "Title2", "Title3"...
  </p>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Title</th>
          <td>title1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Description</th>
          <td>description1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Date</th>
          <td>date1</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br />
      <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Title</th>
          <td>title2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Description</th>
          <td>description2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Date</th>
          <td>date2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br />
      <br />
      <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Title</th>
          <td>title3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="style1" style="height:      23px">Description</th>
          <td style="height: 23px">description3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Date</th>
          <td>date3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br />
      <br />
      <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table style="width: 100%">
              <tr>
                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                <td>title4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                <td>description4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                <td>date4</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Bill-G - really cant understand why your snipped/Edit doesn't work.

Comment: You missed quote and you break the line with src... i fixed it and placed on a snippet and it seem to work...

Comment: Thankyou @A. Meshu for snippeting the code. Would be great if you could fix the rest of the problems here!

Comment: Didn't understand... you want to type "description1" and get the "title1" marked on search results?

Comment: Thanks @A. Meshu. No far from it , I would like to type the letters to title1 and the filter ONLY search the 'Title' table header and not look at the Description or Date table headers. In short - I would the to only like to search titles and nothing else.

Comment: it seems that you are looking for something like that: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp

Comment: Yea @A. Meshu - very similar. Can't think what exact edit(s) I can make to the JavaScript. Thankyou.

Comment: I would try when i be next to a computer

Comment: Thanks - @A. Meshu - would appreciate any other help with this. Would like to have it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As continuation from comments above, and since [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) was something basic that you would like to use, i posted it here. 
I added some notes on the code but the essences are:

1. This is just a really basic approach without any use of libraries.
2. I play with classes in order to hide the table rows and also to mark the result
3. Although i leave the part on the script that `display: none;` the lines of the table, you can manipulate the CSS and delete it from the code.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {   // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]; // this will search on the Title col. You can change this to search on other cols.
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { // found
        tr[i].style.display = ""; 
        tr[i].classList.add("mark"); // mark result
      } 
      else { // didn't found
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
        tr[i].classList.remove("mark"); // unmark result
      }
    }
    if (input.value === '') { // case the input is clear
      tr[i].classList.remove("mark"); // unmark result
      tr[i].style.display = "none";    
    }    
  }
}
```

```css
  table {position: relative; min-width: 320px;} /*  */
  tbody tr {opacity: 0;} /* this will hide the table's info + will show the result under the headers */
  tr.mark {opacity: 1;} /* this will show the result row */ 
/* basic style (markers) to the result row - just for demonstration purpose */
  tr.mark td {background: yellow;} /* (second) col */
  tr.mark td:first-child {background: blue;} /* first col */
  tr.mark td:last-child {background: orange;} /* third  col*/
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search Titles..">
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>  
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>bla bla bla</td>
      <td>description1</td>
      <td>date1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>yada yada yada</td>
      <td>description2</td>
      <td>date2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Another Title</td>
      <td>description3</td>
      <td>date3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope that it is what you searched for, and Enjoy code!

Comment: Thanks so much for your efforts @A. Meshu, but what I'm looking for might be explained better for you by looking at the two pics Ive supplied - the first one explaining the problem and the second showing the desired re-coded result.

Comment: Let's separate. The mechanism (js) is what you want? The problem is with the visual results?

Comment: I think you were on the right track with looking up - w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp. you see the desired result in the pic diagram Ive posted - very similar.

Comment: Also am wanting to keep markjs as is - highlighting a letter at a time as one types.

Comment: I never worked with that library. I guess i can write something similar, but i think you better try to solve that too.... I'll look again tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks @tdjprog - but doesn't work with item 4 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1. you can play with css selectors to achieve your goal:

```
#myTable table tr:first-child td mark {
    background: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}
mark {
    background: initial;
}
```

Solution 2. edit your init function for sibling only titles like this:

```
$(document).ready(function init() {
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');

    /************************************************
      NOTE ::  your last table element doesn't match your template
    ************************************************/
    table = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr:first-child td');
    rows = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr');

    markInstance = new Mark(table);
    input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));
});
```

Have fun